# Issues creating grid of Bootstrap cards when rendering based on Object values

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a hiking trail app that allows users to add trails to a public repository.

I have a  component that renders a Boostrap Card with values passed to it through props. I use `.row` and `.col` to align them into a nice grid.

To generate cards from all of the items in my object, I read data from said object (using map() ) then create a grid of Bootstrap cards. Here is what it is supposed to look like, using the following code :

**Trails.js:**

```
<div id="trails" className="container rounded border shadow">
   <Card className="trailCard" />
</div>
```

**Card.js:**

```
class Card extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card-deck row">
                <div className="col-lg-4 card-col">
                    <div className="card">
                        <img className="card-img-top" alt="" src="https://s24953.pcdn.co/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Templates-Guide-header-1-1024x576.png" />
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title">Card Title</h5>
                            <p className="card-text"><b>Description: </b>This is a longer card test. This is a longer card test.</p>
                            <p className="card-text"><b>Location: </b> This is a longer card test.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-4 card-col">
                    <div className="card">
                        <img className="card-img-top" alt="" src="https://s24953.pcdn.co/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Templates-Guide-header-1-1024x576.png" />
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title">Card Title</h5>
                            <p className="card-text"><b>Description: </b>This is a longer card test. This is a longer card test.</p>
                            <p className="card-text"><b>Location: </b> This is a longer card test.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               [etc..]
     </div>
```

[image]

And here is what it looks like when I read in values from the object and use map() to render new s:

**Trails.js:**

```
                <div id="trails" className="container rounded border shadow">
                    <div className="card-deck-row">
                        {this.props.trailList.map((item) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="col-lg-4 card-col">
                                    <Card
                                        className="trailCard"
                                        trailName={item.trailName}
                                        trailType={item.trailType}
                                        trailDescription={item.trailDescription}
                                        trailLocation={item.trailLocation}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Card.js:**

```
class Card extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div className="card">
                    <img className="card-img-top" alt="" src="https://s24953.pcdn.co/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Templates-Guide-header-1-1024x576.png" />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{this.props.trailName}</h5>
                        <p className="card-text"><b>Location: </b>{this.props.trailLocation}</p>
                        <p className="card-text"><b>Category: </b>{this.props.trailType}</p>
                        <p className="card-text"><b>Description: </b>{this.props.trailDescription}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Card;
```

[image]

How do I make the second example snap to a grid like in the first?

Comment: Does the div with className="card-deck-row" have full width of the screen? If not it might be taking width: auto which will be the width of the card itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<div className="card-deck row">` instead of `<div className="card-deck-row">`. Hope that will fix your issue.